How to smooth out the line animation in an HTML5 canvas?
community!
I am working on a project using HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript/jQuery, where I have multiple animated routes between points on a grid. The animation should smoothly draw lines from point A to point B, but I’m having trouble achieving a smoother movement for the line.

Problem:
The animation is not as smooth as I would like. Instead, the line seems to be "drawn" abruptly from A to B. What I want is for the line to be drawn smoothly, as if it's being traced over time, instead of appearing all at once.
Question:
How can I smooth out this animation so that the line appears more fluid? Any tips on improving the interpolation calculation or how the line is drawn would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!


  $(document).ready(function () {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const points = [];
    const routes = [];
    const pointRadius = 10;
    const gridSize = 60; // Espaçamento entre os pontos
    const numRows = Math.floor(canvas.width / gridSize);
    const numCols = Math.floor(canvas.height / gridSize);
    const animationDuration = 2000; // Tempo total da animação (ajustável)

    // Função para desenhar um ponto
    function drawPoint(x, y, color = 'black') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, pointRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // Função para desenhar a curva completa de A para B
    function drawFullCurve(pointA, pointB, colorStart, colorEnd) {
        const midX = (pointA.x + pointB.x) / 2;
        const midY = (pointA.y + pointB.y) / 2 - 50; // Elevação da curva

        const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, colorStart);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, colorEnd);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(midX, midY, pointB.x, pointB.y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // Função para animar a revelação da curva de A para B
    function animateCurve(pointA, pointB, colorStart, colorEnd, duration) {
        let startTime = performance.now();

        function animateStep(timestamp) {
            const elapsedTime = timestamp - startTime;
            const progress = Math.min(elapsedTime / duration, 1); // Progresso linear de 0 a 1

            // Não limpar o canvas inteiro! Manter as rotas anteriores
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);

            // Calcular posição intermediária com interpolação linear
            const t = progress;
            const midX = (pointA.x + pointB.x) / 2;
            const midY = (pointA.y + pointB.y) / 2 - 50;

            const revealX = (1 - t) * ((1 - t) * pointA.x + t * midX) + t * ((1 - t) * midX + t * pointB.x);
            const revealY = (1 - t) * ((1 - t) * pointA.y + t * midY) + t * ((1 - t) * midY + t * pointB.y);

            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(midX, midY, revealX, revealY);
            ctx.clip();

            drawFullCurve(pointA, pointB, colorStart, colorEnd);

            ctx.restore();

            drawPoint(pointA.x, pointA.y, colorStart);
            drawPoint(pointB.x, pointB.y, colorEnd);

            if (progress < 1) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animateStep);
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(animateStep);
    }

    // Gerar os pontos
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            const x = i * gridSize + gridSize / 2;
            const y = j * gridSize + gridSize / 2;
            points.push({ x, y });
            drawPoint(x, y);
        }
    }

    // Gerar 20 rotas aleatórias
    function generateRandomRoutes() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            const startPoint = points[Math.floor(Math.random() * points.length)];
            const endPoint = points[Math.floor(Math.random() * points.length)];
            routes.push({ startPoint, endPoint });
        }
    }

    generateRandomRoutes();

    // Função para animar as rotas simultaneamente
    function animateRoutes() {
        routes.forEach(route => {
            const colorStart = 'blue';
            const colorEnd = 'red';
            const { startPoint, endPoint } = route;

            // Executa a animação para cada rota sem limpar o canvas
            animateCurve(startPoint, endPoint, colorStart, colorEnd, animationDuration);
        });
    }

    // Executar a animação das rotas
    animateRoutes();
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rotas de Pontos</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
        #canvas-container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            position: relative;
        }
        canvas {
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>). Also show/explain what you already tried but failed so we have a starting point.

The animation looks smooth in Chrome... do you each route drawn one at a time? I don't see any work on how you attempted to change said code.

As you can see in the image running on Chrome, the lines appear jagged. When I zoom in slightly, it gets worse. When I tried using Bezier curves, the lines became smooth, but I couldn't maintain the animation.

Why don't you draw the contents in 2x scale, then ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true; and ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";, then you copy the drawn content as an image and then clear the canvas and drawn the copied image in 1/2 scale (the actual size of the canvas element)? This way the resulting image will be smoothed. By the way, I think your logic is very messy.

@user2804429 Thank you so much for the suggestion! It improved a lot. The lines are now much smoother, and the overall animation looks far better. Rendering at 2x scale and then downscaling really helped to reduce the jagged edges. I appreciate your help!

@Jonny, you're welcome. You can upscale/downscale in higher dimensions (like 3x or 4x instead of 2x and 1/3 or 1/4  instead of 1/2) to get smoother results. But note that the higher you elevate the dimension of scaling the higher will be the cost for the performance. By the way, could you answer your own question with the result you obtained? This way it will be more didactic for other users finding the same difficulties and reach this same question.

Without much modification to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/jwh59kcx/ (though it could benefit from a rewrite)
